# Search and import data from external file.json into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

i need to have any kind of search&list being made, i have an external json file on my desktop and i want JS to read it and then compare to one of my inputs. IF there is a match, get back into inner.html with the results (description of that JSON record)
JSON looks like this (showing only three records)

```
{
    "Port ": "25",
    "Protocol ": "TCP ",
    "Direction ": "Both ",
    "OS ": "All ",
    "Service ": "SMTP ",
    "Action ": "Permit / Restricted ",
    "Rational ": "Explicitly permitted for only BP approved Mail gateways. ",
    "Usage ": "Mail should only be permitted to trusted relays "
},
{
    "Port ": "109",
    "Protocol ": "TCP ",
    "Direction ": "Both ",
    "OS ": "All ",
    "Service ": "POP ",
    "Action ": "Permit / Restricted ",
    "Rational ": "Explicitly permitted for only approved BP Mail Servers. ",
    "Usage ": "Mail should only be permitted to trusted relays "
},
{
    "Port ": "110",
    "Protocol ": "TCP ",
    "Direction ": "Both ",
    "OS ": "All ",
    "Service ": "POP ",
    "Action ": "Permit / Restricted ",
    "Rational ": "Explicitly permitted for only approved BP Mail Servers. ",
    "Usage ": "Mail should only be permitted to trusted relays "
},
```

and my input should be able to split pasted ports, for example tcp-22, ICMP, udp-137 etc. and search them in the JSON and get back with the details.

Comment: Kindly provide some code which you tried.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is currently way too broad of a “question” for this site. (Yes, in quotes, because it is hardly a question at all - you just told us what you _want_, and that does not consider an actual question here in the first place.)